# matplotlib-Reshaping the range of the axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data which ranges between (-1 to 1). But I want to convert it to (0 to 1). Is there any way to convert it in matplotlib.pyplot?

Comment: AFAIK no, you have to scale up your data manually before plotting.

Comment: What does pyplot have to do with this? `data/2+0.5` normalizes the data from [-1,1] to [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple rescaling of your data before plotting. The rescaling of your data to within the range (0, 1) can be done as follows. Let's say you have some data between -1 and 1. This method is general and converts any given range to within 0 and 1. `min` and `max` simply refers to the minimum and maximum of your data set.

```
import numpy as np
old = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
print (old)
# [-1.  -0.77777778 -0.55555556 -0.33333333 -0.11111111  0.11111111 0.33333333  0.55555556  0.77777778  1.]

# Rescaling to 0 and 1
new = (old-min(old))/(max(old)-min(old))
print (new)
# [0. 0.11111111 0.22222222 0.33333333 0.44444444 0.55555556 0.66666667 0.77777778 0.88888889 1.]
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But it is only rescaling the y-axis. I want to re-scaling both y-axis and x-axis.

Comment: @M.ahmed: Do the same thing with your x-data as well.